# Scraped data in code does not match the data from the website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to create a program that scrapes a list of usernames above a number of searches per month from https://namemc.com/minecraft-names. This can easily be done through the website using a search bar, and it takes you to the URL https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?length_op=&length=3&lang=en&searches=50.

I attempted to scrape usernames from this new URL, but I continue to get usernames from the previous URL.

Comment: Hi Basil, welcome to scraping with Python! It looks like your selector is maybe choosing the wrong element. From the page source, it looks like this might be a hard table to select, as there is no ID on the table. Maybe check out this link for help copying a selector from Chrome devtools: https://www.awesome-testing.com/2017/05/how-to-find-test-cssselector-using.html

Comment: What do you mean **variable searches** in expected result is a list of all names that have more searches than the variable searches. Could you please explain with example

Comment: what are values for `searches` and `n_names`?

Comment: @mgrollins I believe I have the correct selector because I'm getting the correct element, it just seems like it's the wrong website even though I have the correct url.

Comment: @VimalThickvijayanVims I just meant the parameter or variable, <searches>, must be the minimum number of searches per name. This can be done manually from the website through a search, and it takes you to a new url, but when I tried to scrape this url it gave me results I did not expect.

Comment: @IvanVinogradov searches would be an integer for the minimum number of searches on a name. Each name must have more searches than the variable, <searches>. n_names is an integer for the maximum number of names returned in the list from the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the website I was requesting blocked webscrapers.

There were 2 fixes for that:

- Use Selenium, as it acts as if it were a user accessing the website
- Use a header with a user-agent when running requests.get(url)

For example:

```py
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('example.com',headers=headers)
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide the right div attrs (as far as i've understood your needs). By changing the div attrs as such

```
soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "row no-gutters py-1 px-3 border-top"}
```

I've gotten output of the sort (a div element)

```
<div class="row no-gutters py-1 px-3 border-top">
<div class="col col-md order-md-1 text-nowrap"><a href="/name/xMilouu_" translate="no">xMilouu_</a></div>
<div class="col-auto col-md order-md-3 text-right">‒</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-md-2 text-md-center"><time datetime="2019-06-28T14:34:55.000Z">2019-06-28T14:34:55.000Z</time></div>
```

You can use

```
name, search, time = element.text.strip().split("\n")
```

printing the variables from this line we get (a line for each element)

```
name: _Delta_Phoenix_    search: ‒   time: 2019-06-28T14:56:01.000Z
name: 1Destruction   search: 3   time: 2019-06-28T14:56:01.000Z
name: Pichu1028      search: 1   time: 2019-06-28T14:56:02.000Z
```

and then apply whatever you need to it

Edit: and a correction, this will ignore the top user found (based on their HTML code), you can reach him with

```
soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "row no-gutters py-1 px-3"}
```

which for me just returns 1 user

Comment: This isn't exactly what I want to be done. I understand that I can grab information and split it into names, searches, and time, but I would like to completely skip that step by using the websites built-in search for names that have above some # of searches. I thought that would be possible by just putting in the new url after using the search. 

Ex:
https://namemc.com/minecraft-names displays names with no filter on # of searches.
https://namemc.com/minecraft-names?length_op=&length=3&lang=&searches=50 displays names with a filter of above 50 searches per month.

Comment: so what I'd expect, is that if the parameter `searches` in my code is some number, then that particular url/website should already display a table with a filter of names with above that number of searches on it, and my code should scrape off that modified url.